# How to split Aggregate Root that have equal identity?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

In DDD, creating smaller aggregates is encouraged where possible, but in a system we are designing we are running into an issue regarding the identity of aggregates.

The system evolves around phyisical events, like music festivals or sports events, and within these events there are separated bounded contexts representing some business use case. For example, there can be `Accreditation` and `Badges`.

#### Solution One

In a first design of the system we had modeled an `Event` aggregate (see Figure 1), where all business logic around `Accreditation`, `Badges`, and future business use cases would live.

[image]

Figure 1: Event aggregate

#### Solution Two

However, this would result in a *huge* aggregate, so we decided it would be best to split these up into smaller aggregates (see Figure 2). `Events` itself was no longer a concept because we had split these up into separate `Accreditation` and `Badges`. However, because they all refer to the same physical event, they only identifier we could come up with was the same `eventId`.

*Implementing this with event sourcing would also raise the issue that there are multiple event streams with the same identifier.*

[image]

Figure 2: Split aggregates with shared identity.

#### Solution Three

Another solution would be the "natural" DDD approach where we would treat the different modules as *Entities* with their own identity (see Figure 3). This however, feels very unnatural and does not represent the actual domain logic. In the implementation we would therefor also need a lookup table of some sort to map the `eventId` to the required `moduleId` (see Figure 4).

[image]

Figure 3: Split aggregates with own identity.

[image]

Figure 4: Lookup table that maps the event to their modules.

#### Question

The question in this case is which of the following solution seems the most efficient and DDD-like approach?

Comment: It might [interest](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=1). Just in case you didn't read it yet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just for clarification (may help with the answers): (1) "within these events there are separated bounded contexts" - as the term "bounded context" is often used in the wrong way, can you say a few words on what do you mean by this? (2) You said "this would result in a huge aggregate" - in what sense, and what are your (practical) concerns? It's not clear from your question or the pictures. (3) Give us a bit more info about the domain - what are the elements of your model? E.g. What are these events (yellow boxes) within the Event aggregate, why they share the same ID, how are they represented?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal to have multiple "aggregates" that are interested in the same [correlation identifier](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CorrelationIdentifier.html).

Mauro Servienti has a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hev65ozmYPI) that discusses how a "monolithic" aggregate might break down into smaller, more focused elements.

If you were doing this with event sourcing, the correlation-identifier that binds the different aggregates together would probably become part of the stream identifier

```
/accreditation/0a4f2945-8480-426a-86b3-5f3abac17a67
/badges/0a4f2945-8480-426a-86b3-5f3abac17a67
```

More generally, you would have a lookup function somewhere that takes the correlation identifier as an argument, and returns the other identifiers that you need, which allows you to start working around the unusual cases that may arise.

```
badgeId = badges(0a4f2945-8480-426a-86b3-5f3abac17a67)
```

Finding a stream given some amount of information is fundamentally a *plumbing* problem, and you'll face the usual complexity vs investment trade offs there.